# Revert to original @Mode options in batch file

Tags: batch, dimensions

I use the command `@mode con: cols=80lines=10` to change the dimensions of a batch file. I was wondering if there was a way to then change back to the original settings?

Answer (score 0):

I figured you can get the current @mode settings like this:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2* skip=3 delims= " %%a in ('mode con') do (
    set _lines=%%b
    goto endline
)
:endline

for /f "tokens=1,2* skip=4 delims= " %%a in ('mode con') do (
    set _cols=%%b
    goto endcol
)
```

and set it back after changing it with this:

```
@mode con: cols=%_cols%lines=%_lines%
```